# Regex to split a string after certain word javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where i have a string "abcDuplicate1" check if the string contains Duplicate word and update the string with "abcDuplicate2" again check the string update it to "abcDuplicate3" etc .
How can we use split method to split the above string after Duplicate

Comment: Please clearly show us the input and expected output.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: This could help (splitting after the word `Duplicate` can be hard, since JS doesn't allow 0-length lookbehinds): `/(.*?Duplicate)(.*)/.exec('abcDuplicate1')`

Comment: FirstScenario -> Input : "abcDuplicate1" Output :"abcDuplicate2" Next Input : "abcDuplicate2" Output: "abcDuplicate3" the value after Duplicate should be incremented if the string has Duplicate keyword

Comment: @Sam  i want to update the text after Duplicate dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, JS's regex implementation doesn't allow for [0-length lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (or something like [PCRE's `\K`](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#resetmatchstart)). This means that it isn't as easy as splitting after "Duplicate" is matched. Instead, though, we can capture both "Duplicate" and the digits following and replace them using [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
var string = 'abcDuplicate1',
    regex = /(Duplicate)(\d+)/;

string = string.replace(regex, function(match, duplicate, number) {
    var newNumber = parseInt(number) + 1;
    return duplicate + newNumber;
});

console.log(string); // abcDuplicate2
```